# Is it old explanation,if he use var thing for his PHP OOP explanation?

Tags: php, oop

Is this old way to explain
for PHP oop, if he use var thing?

for example,

```
<?php
    class person {
        var name;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  The `var` keyword is PHP 4 syntax, deprecated in PHP 5 and no longer used.

If you run your script with `E_STRICT` error reporting, it should notify you of this.

Use `public`, `private`, or `protected` instead.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php for more information.